# Html5 audio element multiple source download preference

Tags: html, audio, download, mp3, opus

If I have an html5 audio element with multiple sources, is there a way I can specify which source should be used when the user wants to download the file vs playing it in the browser (or achieve a similar effect with javascript)? For example, if I have two files, test_file.opus and test_file.mp3, can I signal the browser to play the opus file when the user clicks play, but then to download the mp3 file when they right click and select "save audio as". Typically opus audio files can be smaller, but they can't be played very easily unless the user knows what they're doing.

```
        <audio controls preload="metadata">
            <source src="test_file.opus" type="audio/ogg; codecs=opus">
            <source src="test_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

**Quick Note:** I realize I could provide a download link in an `<a>` tag next to the html5 audio element. I was just curious if there was a way to signal the browser which one should be downloaded vs played in the browser or if there was a way to achieve a similar effect using javascript.

Comment: I'm guessing the browser will allow you to download whatever is playing.  Wouldn't that be preferable?  The browser will have already cached the audio file, so downloading what's cached and playing seems beneficial.

Comment: @Brad I get what you're saying, but the main issue is that if the browser is playing the .opus audio file, then right clicking and selecting "save audio as" will download the .opus file. From my experience, not many people would know how to deal with .opus audio files.